# Как получить код подгружаемый JS из Java

Tags: java, парсер

Есть веб страница, на ней блок который подгружается с помощью JS только после того как нажмешь мышкой на соотв. кнопку. 
Мне же надо программно из Java(JVM) получить html код вместе с этим блоком. 
Пока только получается извлечь html без нужного мне блока.
Как это можно сделать средствами Java ?

P.S Данный JS скрипт данные не подгружает из сервера, поэтому за нужными мне данными не получиться просто обратиться по соотв. URL

Comment: Если JS-скрит не подгружается с сервера динамически, то, очевидно, они уже присутствуют на странице после ее первичной загрузки. Какие проблемы с парсингом HTML-кода?

Comment: @0xFFh В том и проблема что с помощью класса URL извлекаю html, а там нету нужных мне данных, хотя в их js видел как значения прямо из него проставляются

Comment: я не совсем опытен в js, но все данные которые на html, есть в их js скрипте, а их пару сотен строк

Comment: ну тогда здесь может быть немало причин: конкретный JS-скрипт не подгружается, так как сервер "думает", что вы  бот(заголовок User-Agent) или, например, JS генерируется на лету из него самого же - для начала хотя бы точно установите, как интересующий JS попадает на конкретную страницу